# How to get the source code of chromium for editing?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I am not a very advanced programmer so I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is completely unreasonable, but I thought as a fun project I would try to mod an open source browser such as chromium. I am using ubuntu, and I thought I'd just start with getting the source code and compiling. However in the build instructions it says I need at least 100GB of disk space which I do not have and I am very confused as to why this is necessary. Looking at the codebase there seems to be a lot of files that I do not need to build the Linux broswer-only version of chromium (which is less than 200MB in size to download). Is there a way I can get only the files necessary?

Comment: Chromium's source code supports all the major platforms, so most of the source files are shared between different operating systems. That's why you will need the whole repo. The source code is around18-20 GB and compiling files further should accumulate around 20-80 GB

Comment: @Asesh why does compiling files take 20-80 GB?

Comment: Because of files and debug symbols. Release versions will generally take around 20-30 GB while debug version should take around 80-100 GB of disk space

Comment: Currently weighing in at 33Gb download.